# How to count cases of hidden text in shapes?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a macro that checks how many cases of hidden text there are in a document.
I use the `.Find` function.
It looks in the active document `.Rang` and `Shape.TextFrame.TextRange` (and groups of shapes too).

In the end it sums it all up and shows a message like:

> 6 Cases of hidden text were found.

I noticed it ignores hidden text in some cases and in other cases, is inaccurate.

Attached image to see the cases I have tested (Highlights are the hidden characters):
[image]

The macro then sees the following, as "hidden text case":

> A = will find 0 cases  ......  *(perfect)*

> B = will find 4 cases  ......  *(should find **3 cases** (ignoring the ¶ sign even though it is technically a hidden character - although not really part of the text when one would look for as hidden **text**))*

> C = will find 0 cases  ......  *(should find **2 cases**. It overlooks the entire content)*

> D = will find 2 cases  ......  *(perfect)*

Here is the portion that deals with text in shapes:

```
        'Check in shapes that have text
        For Each shp In ActiveDocument.Shapes
            If shp.Type = msoGroup And shp.Visible = msoTrue Then
                    For i = 1 To shp.GroupItems.Count
                         If shp.GroupItems(i).TextFrame.HasText And shp.GroupItems(i).TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Count > 1 Then
                            If shp.GroupItems(i).Visible = msoTrue Then
                                Set rng = shp.GroupItems(i).TextFrame.TextRange
                                With rng.Find
                                    .ClearFormatting
                                    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
                                    .Font.Hidden = True
                                        'count cases
                                         Do While
                                           .Execute
                                           iCount = iCount + 1
                                           hiddenInShapes = True
                                           Selection.MoveRight
                                         Loop
                                End With
                            End If
                         End If
                    Next i
                'If not a group shape
                ElseIf shp.TextFrame.HasText And shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Count > 1 And shp.Visible = msoTrue Then
                    Set rng = shp.TextFrame.TextRange
                    With rng.Find
                        .ClearFormatting
                        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
                        .Font.Hidden = True
                             'count cases
                             Do While
                                .Execute
                                iCount = iCount + 1
                                hiddenInShapes = True
                                Selection.MoveRight
                             Loop
                    End With
            End If
        Next
```

Comment: Not sure that it will solve your problem but where you have `Selection.MoveRight` you need to replace it with `rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd`. At that point of your code ypou are not working with `Selection`.

Comment: For point B the Find is absolutely correct. From your image the entire paragraph seems to have been formatted as hidden and some characters then unhidden. If you want to exclude the para mark from your count you would need something like `If Not rng.Text = vbCr Then iCount = iCount +1`

Comment: Thank you, Timothy, I used your suggestion about the para mark, and it ignores those!

Comment: As for your other suggestion, it didn't work. But I figured out a workaround using 

```If iCount = iCountOld And shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters(1).Font.Hidden = True And shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters(1) <> vbCr Then iCount = iCount + 1```
- which checks an old counter (i added ```iCounterOld``` variable) against the current iCouner and if the statement is True it adds one up as a case that's found (regardless of how many paragraphs the shape has - which is not critical, as long as it counts it as anther instance of hidden text. Thanks!

Comment: Just remember that each time `Selection.MoveRight` gets executed the insertion point in the document is moved. As your code isn't using the `Selection` object that statement shouldn't be there. It is usual when using Find without Replace in VBA to collapse the range.

Comment: you're right, ```selection``` shouldn't be there. I'll delete it. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I have revised the code -

- ignores the paragraph mark character
- includes cases, where the entire shape content (text) is hidden - it'll include as one more case
- minor corrections made as well

(thanks to Timothy's suggestions)

```
        'Check in shapes that have text
        For Each shp In ActiveDocument.Shapes
            If shp.Type = msoGroup And shp.Visible = msoTrue Then
                    For i = 1 To shp.GroupItems.Count
                         If shp.GroupItems(i).TextFrame.HasText And shp.GroupItems(i).TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Count > 1 Then
                            If shp.GroupItems(i).Visible = msoTrue Then
                                Set rng = shp.GroupItems(i).TextFrame.TextRange
                                With rng.Find
                                    .ClearFormatting
                                    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
                                    .Text=""
                                    .Font.Hidden = True
                                        'count cases
                                        iCountOld = iCount
                                        Do While .Execute
                                            If rng.Text <> vbCr Then iCount = iCount + 1
                                            hiddenInShapes = True
                                        Loop
                                        If iCount = iCountOld And shp.GroupItems(i).TextFrame.TextRange.Characters(1).Font.Hidden = True And shp.GroupItems(i).TextFrame.TextRange.Characters(1) <> vbCr Then iCount = iCount + 1
                                End With
                            End If
                         End If
                    Next i
                'If not a group shape
                ElseIf shp.TextFrame.HasText And shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Count > 1 And shp.Visible = msoTrue Then
                    Set rng = shp.TextFrame.TextRange
                    With rng.Find
                        .ClearFormatting
                        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
                        .Text=""
                        .Font.Hidden = True
                            'count cases
                            iCountOld = iCount
                            Do While .Execute
                                If rng.Text <> vbCr Then iCount = iCount + 1
                                hiddenInShapes = True
                            Loop
                            If iCount = iCountOld And shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters(1).Font.Hidden = True And shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters(1) <> vbCr Then iCount = iCount + 1
                    End With
            End If
        Next
```